# Error using microtype and xeCJK package

Tags: microtype, xecjk

I’d like to use the `microtype` and `xeCJK` packages in one document:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{microtype}
\expandafter\let\csname xetex_suppressfontnotfounderror:D\endcsname
\suppressfontnotfounderror
% the above two lines are a necessary fix to a temporary problem
% of a package lagging behind in CTAN
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Source Han Sans}
\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

but keep getting this error:

```
!Undefined control sequence
<argument> \ifpdf 

                  \expandafter \@secondoftwo \else \expandafter \@firstoftwo...
l.7 \begin{document}
```

I do not get the error if I remove either xeCJK or microtype. None of the packages list an incompatibility in their respective documentation. Is there an error on my side, or a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in one of the loaded packages using this without definition, but you can add

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
```

to the preamble to get things working.

Seems to be line 1174 of `microtype.sty` . One possible fix would be adding `\RequirePackage{ifpdf}` as in:

```
        {\RequirePackage{ifpdf}\ifpdf\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi}%
```

I'll ping the author.

Comment: But, why does it work when I remove the xeCJK package?

Comment: @Philipp that line is in a conditional block of code only used in the cjk case (no idea what it is trying to do but that is only time it does it:-)

Comment: Thanks. It should only be temporary then, with a fix at hand and the package well-maintained.

Answer (score 2):

The `xeCJK` package fools LaTeX into thinking that `CJKutf8.sty` has been loaded:

```
78 \clist_map_inline:nn { CJKulem , CJKvert , CJKpunct , CJKutf8 , CJK }
79   {
80     \xeCJK_if_package_loaded:nTF {#1}
81       { \msg_error:nnn { xeCJK } { incompatible-package } {#1} }
82       { \tl_const:cn { ver@ #1 . \c__xeCJK_package_ext_tl } { 9999/99/99 } }
83   }
```

Next, `microtype.sty` has

```
1165 \MT@addto@setup{%
1166   \@ifpackageloaded{CJK}{%
1167     \@ifpackagelater{CJK}{2006/10/17}% 4.7.0
1168       {\def\MT@orig@pickupfont{\CJK@ifundefined\CJK@plane}}%
1169       {\def\MT@orig@pickupfont{\@ifundefined{CJK@plane}}}%
1170     \g@addto@macro\MT@orig@pickupfont
1171       {{\expandafter\ifx\font@name\relax\define@newfont\fi}}%
1172     \@ifpackageloaded{CJKutf8}%
1173       {\@ifpackagelater{CJKutf8}{2008/05/22}% 4.8.0
1174         {\ifpdf\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi}%
1175         {\@firstoftwo}}%
1176       {\@firstoftwo}%
[...]
```

and here the problem shows, because `CJKutf8.sty` has

```
32 \RequirePackage{ifpdf}
```

but the package code is not input, so the package is not read in.

The `xeCJK` package should load `ifpdf`, because the issue is its fault. On the other hand it's very reasonable that also `microtype` loads it.